# Recording iPad Task for User Replay

Tags: ios, objective-c, capture

Sorry if this might be an obvious question however I'm relatively new to iOS.

Lets say I have a task where the user must drag a puck around a course as quickly as possible.

Is there a way of being able to record the user doing the puck task on the iPad and then show them a video of them just doing the exercise that they can then export. The video would literally just be a screen capture of the iPad itself with the puck moving around.

Is this possible? And how ?:) Preferably without using third part libraries

Thanks,

Comment: Is this even possible ?:)